# List of Union only accepts first type of union with Pydantic

Tags: python, list, union, python-typing, pydantic

With the following python type definitions:

```
import pydantic
from typing import List, Union
import sys
import pprint

class TypeA(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name:str = "Type A"
    type_a_spesific:float = 1337

class TypeB(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name:str = "Type B"
    type_b_spesific:str = "bob"


class ReturnObject(pydantic.BaseModel):
    parameters:List[Union[TypeA, TypeB] ]

parameters = list()
parameters.append(TypeA(name="item 1", type_a_spesific=69))
parameters.append(TypeB(name="item 2", type_b_spesific="lol"))

ret = ReturnObject(parameters = parameters)

print(f"Python version: {pprint.pformat(sys.version_info)}")
print(f"Pydantic version: {pydantic.__version__}")
print(ret.json(indent=3))
print(ret)
```

The version output looks like this:

```
Python version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=11, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Pydantic version: 1.10.11
```

I would expect the parameter list to contain two objects with different type like this:

### Expected

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "item 1",
            "type_a_spesific": 69
        },
        {
            "name": "item 2",
            "type_b_spesific": "lol"
        }
    ]
}

parameters=[TypeA(name='item 1', type_a_spesific=69.0), TypeB(name='item 2', type_b_spesific="lol")]
```

However what comes out instead is this:

### Actual

```
{
   "parameters": [
      {
         "name": "item 1",
         "type_a_spesific": 69.0
      },
      {
         "name": "item 2",
         "type_a_spesific": 1337
      }
   ]
}

parameters=[TypeA(name='item 1', type_a_spesific=69.0), TypeA(name='item 2', type_a_spesific=1337)]
```

For some reason the **List[ Union[ TypeA, TypeB ]]** does not work. *What gives*?

Comment: What version of PyDantic are you on? on 2.0.3, `.json` no longer supports keyword arguments, and is being deprecated, but without the indent argument, it gives the output you would expect

Comment: what does `print(ret)` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: How can I know what version I have at runtime? This is running inside a docker container so I can't readily look at pip freeze

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Output of print(ret) is parameters=[TypeA(name='item 1', type_a_spesific=69.0), TypeA(name='item 2', type_a_spesific=1337)]

Comment: I noticed that if I run this outside my docker container it produces the expected output and you are correct  ret.json is not  supported, it wants to use ret.model_dump_json() outside docker indicating that a newer version of pydantic will solve the issue

Comment: you can shell into a container, `docker run -it <container> -e bash` then you can use pip list, but you can also just check `import pydantic; print(pydantic.__version__)`. Anyway, yeah, sounds like you have version lower than 2. You should probably update, 2 makes some changes though. I believe the most recent release is 2.4

Comment: Also, probably important to note, this really has nothing to do with python typing per se, but rather, how the pydantic library is handling type hints. I would edit the title to use "Pydantic" instead of "Python typing"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I updated the question title to reflect your observation that this is in fact about Pydantic and not about python typing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments by @juanpa.arrivillaga I found the answer myself;

This is a bug(feature?) of Pydantic **1.x**. If I upgrade to use Pydantic **2.x** then it behaves as expected.