# How to specify version of module installed from git repo with pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, version, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

In my **Python** **FastAPI** app, I need **Pydantic** version 2 to solve [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203896/list-of-union-only-accepts-first-type-of-union-with-pydantic/77204842) with `Unions` that is fixed in version 2 only.

Since **FastAPI** version 0.100.0 and onward supports **Pydantic** v2, I was first hopeful that depending on **Pydantic** v2 would work fine, however another indirect depdendency in my project called **sqlmodel** specifies to only support **Pedantic** 1.x.

**sqlmodel** is incidently [also written by tiangolo](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) which is the [author of FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and he stated that **sqlmodel** would get a version bump with support for **Pydantic** v2, [the discussion can be seen here](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/532). But this has taken some time and has caused a lot of problems for many users and prompted someone to [create a fork of sqlmodel, patching it to support **Pydantic** v2](https://github.com/honglei/sqlmodel).

I want to use this forked version of **sqlmodel** in my project to get **Pydantic** v2 support installed without the dependency problems. I know it is possible to specify a git repo directly in my `requirements.txt` file using the `-e git+https://github.com/author/project.git@branch_tag_or_hash#egg=packagename` syntax, however when I try this with the fork of **sqlmodel** I get an error because now **sqlmodel** has version "0" according to **pip**.

The exact syntax I have used in my requirements.txt looks like this:

```
-e git+https://github.com/honglei/sqlmodel.git@main#egg=sqlmodel
```

and the exact error message after running pip install -r requirements.txt looks like this:

```
ERROR: Cannot install sqlmodel 0 (from git+https://github.com/honglei/sqlmodel.git@main#egg=sqlmodel) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
```

As you can clearly see, pip thinks we are installing "version 0" of sqlmodel now which is clearly not the case.

So there are two questions;

1. How can I convince pip that the git fork of **sqlmodel** is actually version *0.0.9* or some other arbitrary value that makes it be accepted as the latest version of the package during dependency resolution?
2. Taking a step back, are there any more elegant ways to resolve this? It seems quite radical and hacky to depend on a fork in github, but I don't see any other way of having FastAPI and Pydantic v2 in my app at this point.

Comment: Regarding question 2: the underlying issue is that SQLModel is a severely underdeveloped library that hasn't had a release in over a year. I used it when it first came out, and since then, SQLAlchemy (the library SQLModel is based on, which handles all database interactions) has improved their typing support a lot. I ended up ditching SQLModel, I would recommend you do the same, at least until it at the very least gets a 0.1.0 release.

Comment: @M.O. I would love to ditch sqlmodel however it is an indirect dependency in my project. I don't even know which package depends on it. I will surely make a search to see if I can cut it out completely.

Comment: You could have a look at [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) to view the dependency tree and see which package depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/11612918) for the syntax. Also, you don't need `-e`, that's for making the install *editable*, which is only useful when you’re working on that package yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it does not solve my problem. It is kind of hard to explan, but let me try: The latest version of sqlmodel in pypi is 0.0.8. Other packages in pypi that depend on sqlmodel will have a dependency saying something like "sqlmodel>=0.0.8". The git repo has no tags or branches even resembling a clean version name. The only branch there is "main". Dependency resolver will NOT think "main>=0.0.8", therefore my git package is not selected and dependency resolution fails. How can I give my git package a made up version number that will make dependency resolution work?

Comment: Ah, I see that you solved it. Another solution  probably would have been to uninstall the pypi version and then install the fork.

Answer (score 0):

I will add the answer that solved the problem for me in case someone else faces the same issue. It is not elegant and I hope there is another better solution out there. Please share if you know of one.

Here is what I did to solve the problem.

1. Fork the fork (you can find my version [here](https://github.com/mrdeveloperdude/sqlmodel/))
2. Update the version number of the project. In this case I opened [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/mrdeveloperdude/sqlmodel/blob/main/pyproject.toml) and put `version="0.0.9"` instead of `version="0"`.
3. Create a [new tag](https://github.com/mrdeveloperdude/sqlmodel/tree/0.0.9) with the name "0.0.9". This process was kind of messy in github, I ended up create a branch, a release and then finally a tag. I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it.
4. Put the following line in my requirements.txt: `git+https://github.com/mrdeveloperdude/sqlmodel.git@0.0.9#egg=sqlmodel`. Please note there is no "-e" as this would simply mean I want an [editable](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) package which is not the case.
5. run `pip install -r requirements.txt` again
6. Profit!

It did complain a lot but in the end those complaints were just words in my terminal. My app got Pydantic 2 support and all was well.

Final words: I think this is ugly, unecessary, hacky and inelegant in ways that just.. it makes my skin crawl frankly. I hope there is a hidden option somewhere that would allow one to just invent a version and apply that to a git repo without having to fork it.